# How can I reverse the "includes()" method to "not-includes()" and retrieve the not included value?

Tags: javascript, methods, include

Im trying to retrieve the **not included value** in the second array, by using the following code:

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (let i of arr1) {
    if (arr2.includes(i)) {
      newArr.push(i)
    }
  }
  return newArr
}

console.log(
  diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
)
```

Is there any way I can use another method to do this. I tried indexOf but I don't want the index.

Thank you

Comment: use `!` . That means `not`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter()`:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 5];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let result = arr2.filter(a2 => !arr1.includes(a2));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: No real need for `every` - `includes` still works `arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item))`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!arr2.includes(i)) {
     newArr.push(i)
   }
```

! means not

You could always use `else` as well, but it's more lines of code:

```
if (arr2.includes(i)) {
     // newArr.push(i)
 }  else {
    newArr.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, everything in arr1, is in arr2, so you would get nothing

Comment: Right, need to go the other way around!

Answer (score 0):

```
const a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const a2 = [1, 2, 3, 5];

function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const frequencies = arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((frequencies, number) => {
    const frequency = frequencies[number];
    frequencies[number] = frequency ? frequency + 1 : 1;
    return frequencies;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(frequencies).filter(number => frequencies[number] === 1);
}
```

Comment: That's way to complex for me to wrap... But thanks for the effort!

Comment: You are looking for the numbers that appear only in one of the arrays.

I merged the two arrays and created an object where the keys are the numbers and the values are the number of times they appear in the merged array.

Then removed the ones that occur more than 1 time.

I didn't want to use includes because it goes through the array everytime until it doesn't find what you are looking for.